# Not sure how to convert cursor to this method return type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I'm asking this question again 'cuz the provided answers are not compatible with the new version of Android Paging Library.
My Dao function is as following

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items")
fun getAll() : DataSource.Factory<Int, List<Item>>
```

There's not a something different from the samples provided by google-developers but i keep getting the following error :

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
                                                                                                                              ^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

any ideas of the reason of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and the explanation is that `DataSource.Factory` will already return a `PaginedList` of the items, so there's no need of calling it with a `List<Item>`.